# System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Unclosed chain.'

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get an information from the web (`adress` in my code) with HtmlAgilityPack in C#, but I have to wait until the `<div class="center fs22 green lh32">` is loaded on the page.

```
            var url = $"https://www.webpage.com/test{info}";
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.LoadFromBrowser(url, html =>
        {
            return !html.Contains("<div class=\"center fs22 green lh32\"></div>");
        });
        string adress = doc.DocumentNode
              .SelectSingleNode("//td/span[@id='testedAddress")
              .Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Unfortunally I always get this error when I start my code :
[image: unclosed chain error]
**Translation :** 'Unclosed chain.'
[image: quickwatch view]

How can I pass this error ?

Comment: You might want to work on an english OS, english error messages are a lot easier to google.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is already in English, but the error messages stay in French

Comment: @Lulucmy: I think that depends on the language of the .NET framework that is active on your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs on the following line:

```
.SelectSingleNode("//td/span[@id='testedAddress")
```

There is a `'` and a `]` missing at the end of that XPath expression. That inner part incompletely enclosed in `'` is the "chain" (actually, a *string* in English, or "chaîne de caractères" in French) the error message is talking about.

So, the line should read instead:

```
.SelectSingleNode("//td/span[@id='testedAddress']")
```

Comment: I tried with, and nothing has changed, always the same error... https://i.imgur.com/HfIExbT.png

Comment: @Lulucmy: Sorry, I missed that there were two characters missing. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks; it is working but I now have a new error, do I have to open a new question ?

Comment: @Lulucmy: Yes, please (unless the error is directly caused by an issue in the solution proposed in this answer). Beware of creating [*chameleon questions*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Also, note that with the one-problem-per-question system, it's a lot easier for later visitors to find your question if they're having the same problem.